# Ports required for Apache Ignite Cluster

Tags: ignite

This question may be duplicate.

I am building Ignite cluster.
Observed that intercommunication between nodes require multiple ports to be opened.

So far, I opened ports like 47100 and 11211.
It's tedious to raise open request for every newly found port to IT dept.

Require list of all ports used by Ignite so I can open ports at once.

Comment: Check out this link: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Which-ports-does-ignite-cluster-need-to-run-normally-td8031.html

Answer (score 1):

It's all configurable, so this is only true if you've not changed any of the defaults and only have one node running per machine, but: 10800 (JDBC/ODBC), 11211 (TCP connector), 47100 (listener), 47500 (discovery). As [Denis notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618478/ports-required-for-apache-ignite-cluster/53618933?noredirect=1#comment94117660_53618933), you only really *need* the last two but that depends on your application.

Comment: I would rather say, that 10800 is JDBC/ODBC port, and 11211 is a TCP connector port. They are optional, and may be opened if you really need these interfaces.