# Any idea why this port is not reachable from another GCP instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I have created an Ignite database instance that should accept connections from a thin client on port 10800. After SSH-ing into that instance and running `netstat -tunlp` I can see:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10800           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      871/java
...
```

A portscan from another host shows this however:

```
abcdef@ssh-instance:~$ sudo nmap -sS -p10800-10800 x.x.x.x
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-08 03:33 UTC
Nmap scan report for a.b.d.e.f (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00020s latency).

PORT      STATE    SERVICE
10800/tcp filtered gap

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.44 seconds
```

So it seems unreachable. Initially I thought that the GCP firewall was blocking the port, but the rule `default-allow-internal` is enabled, so the port should be exposed. I also tried to enable firewall logs while connecting, but no logs are generated.

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: 1) Did you enable a firewall ingress rule for port 10800? 2) Are both systems in the same VPC? 3) Are you using public or private IP addresses? More details are required to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 1) There is no ingress rule for port 10800. 2) Both are in the default network. 3) I am using internal IP addresses (I reserved a static internal IP for the database).

Comment: @JohnHanley I turned on the GCP firewall logging and it looks like the connection goes through the GCP firewall ('disposition: ALLOWED' shows in the log for this attempt). Very mysterious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers! I tried a few more things and in the end discovered that my instance needed to have an external IP. After creating an instance with external IP, the instance was reachable! (I am still connecting on an internal IP, my firewall fortunately still blocks connections from the internet)

Comment: You do not need a public IP address. Your solution indicates possibly a different problem. Your instance did not have a route to the Internet and by enabling a public IP you gave it a route. You probably need to set up a NAT for your internal private network.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite uses more ports, and port ranges, not only port 10800 (which is just JDBC connector port)

Have a look here, these are the ports uses in standard configuration:

- https://dzone.com/articles/a-simple-checklist-for-apache-ignite-beginners
- [Ports required for Apache Ignite Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618478/ports-required-for-apache-ignite-cluster)

Probably port 10800 is not the port you need, or not just that.

So, it could change a lot, based on your configuration.
How do you set up the cluster?
How do you start the server nodes and specify the nodes list?

By Java code, you can specify the nodes list doing something like this...

```
TcpDiscoverySpi        discover = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder   = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();

finder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("10.10.10.1", "10.10.10.2")); // input the relevant IP addresses
discover.setIpFinder(finder);
```

... using the proper (local, internal) IP addresses, of course.

One last note on GCP testing, please run some netcat tests on your nodes.
If you start a listener on one server, you should be able to connect from another.

Start netcat listener on first server (eg: this server has private IP 10.0.0.1)

```
# netcat -l -p 10800
```

Then connect to the listener from another server (inside your GCP private network)

```
# netcat 10.10.10.1 10800
```

Please tests more ports, as needed.

By default GCP settings:

- you should be able to connect from GCP to GCP on internal/private IP
  addresses (even instances running on different GCP zones)
- you should NOT be able to connect to public/external IP addresses
  even if connection is coming from GCP instances

Hope it helps somehow!