# How to open the bare minimum number of ports for Ignite when only using a simple distributed cache?

Tags: java, ignite

This question is related to:
[Ports required for Apache Ignite Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618478/ports-required-for-apache-ignite-cluster)

In my case, I have only one use for Apache ignite and that is for several simple distributed `Cache<String, String>` objects. I have 6 server nodes and they all need to asynchronously share these caches.

My networking team wants to open only the bare minimum number of ports for my use case. We don't need anything fancy. We will not be using multi-cast. We will be specifying the `IP,Port` of all 6 nodes for use with discovery.

Here is the code I will be using:

```
TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500"));
tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
```

So far so good. I ran a test on a development cluster and I can verify the cache is properly distributing. This development cluster is 2 JBoss servers on the same machine.

Now I am moving to deploy this on 6 separate VMs.

Will this become `ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("10.0.1.5:47500", "10.0.1.6:47500", "10.0.1.7:47500", "10.0.1.8:47500", "10.0.1.9:47500", "10.0.1.10:47500"));` ?

I have have about 8 different `Cache<String, String>` in my code. Does the number of Cache objects I'm using affect the number of ports I need?

Is 47500 the only port being used here in my use case? If not, which other ports do I need? How do I set this up to use the absolute bare minimum number of ports for my use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **bare minimum** 
you need **discovery** (port 47500 by default) and **communication** (port 47100 by default)

see: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery
and: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration#communication

 pay attention to port range parameters, as Ignite will use it to find an available
port if the default one is taken.
see:
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/TcpDiscoverySpi.html#setLocalPortRange-int-
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/communication/tcp/TcpCommunicationSpi.html#setLocalPortRange-int-

**The following are optional:** 
8080 — REST API port - https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/restapi

11211 - for using visor/control.sh tools
   https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script#connecting-to-cluster
   https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/visor-cmd

49112 — the default JMX port (this one is subject to change in later releases)

10800 — thin client/JDBC/ODBC port
   https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients#configuring-thin-client-connector